# Visual GC in Java VisualVM via jstadt for remote Tomcat

Tags: java, tomcat, garbage-collection, jvisualvm, jstatd

I'm trying to get the memory layout of a remote Tomcat visualized with Visual GC in Java VisualVM.
On the Linux server which hosts the Tomcat jstatd is running (including **tools.policy** and the proper [-J]-Djava.rmi.server.hostname=[SERVER_IP], which is to be found in the jvm options of the Tomcat as well).
The connection from VisualVM to the server/jstatd works properly:

[image: Connection tree of jvisualVM]

But all i can see in the **Visual GC** tab of the Jstatd connection are the memory details of the **Jstatd JVM itself**, not the data of the Tomcat.
**Edit:** And in the Visual GC tab of the Tomcat connection (prod apl01 jmx) I'm being told: "Not supported for this JVM"
Testing this with a system we run inhouse I get proper data here.

The remote Tomcat runs with it's own user "tomcat". 
Must jstatd be started by this user as well?
Or is there another issue I might be missing?

Any working alternative like another visual tool that provides a visualization similar to the one below would be absolutely acceptable.
We're using **Yourkit** as well, but I couldn't find anything in there that resembles Visual GC easy to understand style.
[image: Visual GC memory layout visualization]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Having done some more research and tests on our locale development environment i realized that we haven't had the right permissions on the production environment.
So i asked the admin to add jstatd to the sudoers list and voilà it works as expected:

`sudo /usr/java/latest/bin/jstatd -J-Djava.security.policy=/home/empulse/tools.policy -J-Djava.rmi.server.hostname=[SERVER_IP]`

Answer (score 1):

On remote server create policy,

```
vim /tmp/tools.policy
```

Add Permission,

```
grant codebase "file:${java.home}/../lib/tools.jar" {
   permission java.security.AllPermission;
};
```

And start jstatsd,

```
jstatd -J-Djava.security.policy=/tmp/tools.policy -J-Djava.rmi.server.hostname=<public_ip>
```

and you ready are with Visual GC inside VisualVM on local machine.